# SFC /scannow reports "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation"

Tags: windows-vista, 32-bit

I tried to run `sfc /scannow`, but it reports `Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation`.  I have a Windows Vista 32bit operating system.  Please suggest the cause of this message.

Comment: To add to this I'll like to mention I have "User Access Control"enabled

Comment: Are you running it as Administrator?

Comment: Thanks @Huskehn yes I am running the same as administrator..cmd>run as administrator and then I go.here is the screenshot of the message http://puu.sh/4tf6E.png

Comment: Try booting into Startup Repair (press F8 on boot) and run the command from there.

Comment: I second Huskehn's idea, I've had a similar issue and solution twice before, and both times it took a while to solve. Here is an example: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/cant-system-restore-chkdsk-wont-run/d4aaa1df-00ec-4ddc-abf5-0c8a2e53eee4

Answer (score 1):

Open the services MMC snapin (`services.msc`) and male sure that the service "Windows module Installer" is running. This service is required to run sfc on Vista/7/8.

Comment: yes it's running as I have said it goes uptil 98% and then the said error is showed

Comment: can you upload the file **CBS.log**.

Comment: I have uploaded the cbs.log file..Please find here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vw9iuwuznztme6l/CBS.log

Comment: you get the error c0190005 which can mean ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED or STATUS_RM_NOT_ACTIVE. Make sure the Trustedinstaller has writing permissions to the folder **C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingRenames**

Comment: thanks @magicandre1981 but it would be better if you could guide me on this ..I'll like like to tell the message is shown while I use sfc /scannow after proceeding to about 98%

Comment: here is a guide to add trustedinstaller back: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2007/01/30/sysk-277-how-to-bring-back-the-trustedinstaller.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So.. I initially suspected this could be [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20190324141821/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2017/12/21/vista-and-windows-server-2008-serving-stack-update/) of [the](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/windows-modules-installer-error126/2a45788d-c1e5-4b62-a5b1-2410cbcbf813) many [issues](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00580ff7-4412-459b-b176-c8a002ebd740/sfc-problem-quotwindows-resource-protection-could-not-start-the-repair-servicequot) with *TrustedInstaller*, since my SP2 WinPE seemed to be the only version ever unable to launch it manually from cmd.

But after banging my head for a day and mashing up every system folder at a time, I found out SFC wasn't working because I had the important `C:\Windows\System32\Config\COMPONENTS` corrupted (other files in there may also be relevant for somebody else).
Thankfully, in the recovery enviroment you can [restore](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-registry/#Command_Prompt) its automatic backup from the `RegBack` folder (or you can decide to perform an [Upgrade (re)Install](https://www.vistax64.com/threads/repair-install-for-vista.88236/).. if you still manage to boot the OS).

Make also sure your disk is in good health with `chkdsk` beforehands.